# How to zoom screen on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, 20.04

In previous versions of Ubuntu there was always an easy way to zoom into the desktop with Compiz or something else. You could set a shortcut and zoom in by a factor of ~1.25 using the keyboard shortcut and each time you pressed the shortcut, it would zoom in by the same factor. Ubuntu 20.04 does not allow Compiz and its magnification system is very crude. If you use the keyboard shortcut, it zooms by a factor of 2. To zoom by a factor of 1.25, you have to manually go into the Universal Access settings and toggle. Moreover, the zooming seems to make the image a little too pixellated than in the previous versions. (Attaching images to make it clear)

[image: Have to manually toggle in Universal Access settings for a 1.25 factor zoom]

[image: Keyboard shortcut yields 2x zoom and causes too much pixellation]

Is there a way around all of this? At the very least, can I manually set the keyboard shortcut to zoom by a factor of 1.25 and not 2?

Comment: what screen do you refer to? Please [edit] your question with further detail about what you are seeking to achieve.

Comment: If it is any help...there is xzoom which is a sort of magnifying glass for a rectangular area of the screen, and most apps allow Ctrl+ and Ctrl- to zoom in and out (except LibreOffice).

Comment: "by a factor of 1 or above and not less" — I have never used it, but now looked at the settings UI for it and tried it briefly; Now I wonder wouldn't a zoom factor less than 1 be zooming *out*? IOW making things smaller?

Comment: Please describe what you would consider an "elegant way".

Comment: What do you mean by "Ubuntu 20.04 does not allow Compiz"? I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with Compiz. I have just tried Magnifier (never used it before) and it works OK.

Comment: Can you tell me how you use Compiz on Ubuntu 20.04?

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to do this if you're using Gnome (which you should be IMHO)

- <kbd>Super</kbd>+ <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd> : Toggle zoom enabled/disabled (when enabled, the next two keyboard shortcuts become active)
- <kbd>Super</kbd> +  <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> : Zoom in (increases zoom factor by 1.0)
- <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>-</kbd>  : Zoom out (decreases zoom factor by 1.0, until it is 1.0)

credit:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33243/does-gnome-3-support-desktop-zoom

**UPDATE**
To control the zoom factor:

In Ubuntu GNOME, the default keyboard shortcuts for screen zoom provide a fixed zoom factor. However, if you want to have more incremental control over the zoom factor, you can use the GNOME Tweaks tool. Here's how you can adjust the zoom factor:

1. Install GNOME Tweaks if you don't have it already:

   ```bash
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
   ```
2. Open GNOME Tweaks. You can find it by searching for "Tweaks" in the Activities overview or by running the following command:

   ```bash
   gnome-tweaks
   ```
3. In GNOME Tweaks, navigate to the "Keyboard & Mouse" section.
4. Click on the "Additional Layout Options" button.
5. Look for the "Zoom" section and expand it.
6. Here, you'll find options to set the "Zoom In" and "Zoom Out" increments. You can adjust the zoom factor by specifying a custom value in the "Zoom In" and "Zoom Out" fields. For example, you can set the "Zoom In" increment to 0.2 and the "Zoom Out" increment to -0.2 to have smaller, more incremental zoom steps.
7. Close GNOME Tweaks.

Once you've adjusted the zoom increments using GNOME Tweaks, you can use the configured keyboard shortcuts to zoom in and out with the specified increments.

Please note that the availability and functionality of GNOME Tweaks may vary depending on your Ubuntu version and desktop environment.

Comment: This question is not about the keyboard shortcuts for zooming in, but a more refined way of doing it than doubling the size of the screen, which the zoom feature on Gnome does.

Comment: @user178834 see updated answer, thanks.